# How can I register my username?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I know this belongs in meta, but I cannot anonymously post a question there.

I have clicked "register" and logged in with my Google account, Facebook account, and I have even created a stackexchange account and my user profile still shows "unregistered." I cannot upvote, etc.  I have tried clearing cookies, using a different browser, and each time I am able to log in using any of the above to an unregistered user. Any troubleshooting tips? I would like to participate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug that they haven't figured out how to fix yet. A developer fixed it manually for your account; you should be able to login with either OpenID now

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!